# How to check if a product already exist in prestashop using WebService based on the Reference?

Tags: php, api, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using this script for Prestashop 1.7.7 (which works fine) to create a product inside prestashop (using webservice) but sometimes it will create the same product multiples times..

How can i first check, if there is already an existing product with value of "$product_barcode" as reference ?

So that if this product already exist i can skip this one.

```
//on récupère les infos relatives au produit
$product_model = $result[0]['product_model'];
$product_barcode = $result[0]['product_barcode'];
$product_price = $result[0]['product_price'];
$product_vat = $result[0]['product_vat'];

//on va rechercher le produit a modifier sur le prestashop
$parameters = array();

try {
    // creating webservice access
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, '***********************', true);
 
    $xmlResponse = $webService->get(['url' => $url . '/api/products?schema=blank']);
    $productXML = $xmlResponse->product[0]; //Récupération du schéma de création
    $productXML->name->language[0] = $product_model;
    $productXML->description->language[0] = "A MODIFIER";
    $productXML->description->language[1] = "test de description FR";
    $productXML->price = $product_price;
    $productXML->reference = $product_barcode;
    $productXML->id_category_default = 2;
    $productXML->state = 1;//Cette valeur doit être à 1 pour que le produit soit visible dans les listings admin
    $productXML->id_tax_rules_group = $product_vat;
 
    //On ajoute également dans une catégorie
    //La première catégorie est déjà présente dans le schéma
    $productXML->associations->categories->category[0]->id = 30;
    
    //Envoi des informations au webservice
    $opt = ['resource' => 'products'];
    $opt['postXml'] = $xmlResponse->asXML();
    $return = $webService->add($opt);
    $id = $return->product->id;
    echo "Creation du produit $id <br />";
 
    } catch ( PrestaShopWebserviceException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Request /api/products/?filter[reference]=[your_reference] and check if returns any product.

You can filter by others fields as explained in https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/tutorials/advanced-use/additional-list-parameters/